# Using the JS SBT Librarys without running the SBTSDK on a Server

Tags: ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

can the JavaScript librarys from the SBTSDK used standalone without running the SBTSDK on a server?
So that i can just include local js files from the sbt and use the APIs.
Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't believe so as it relies on Core PHP/Java/J2EE libraries to proxy the requests to the domain/server which hosts IBM Connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of cross origin domain restriction on a browser you won't be able to do that

there are two minimal Ajax proxies included in the toolkit, which doesn't require to deploy the full SBTSDK to a server.

this is the java based proxy https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/tree/master/sdk/com.ibm.sbt.proxy.web

this is the php based proxy https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/tree/master/php/php-core

relevant documentation for PHP deployment https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/wiki/Introducing-the-SBT-PHP-Core - the java proxy is configured as other part of the SDK using managed-beans.xml and the sbt.properties files.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul Bastide: I thought the SBT can be used as a simple JavaScript Wrapper in my JS Web Application by including e.g. sbt-standalone.js (similar to e.g. jquery)? I could write the whole logic to consume the IBM Connections API on my own in jquery. For sure I need to enbale CORS on serverside that this works. Is it really true that  the SBT can't be used for this usecase?

Comment: @Lorenzo has the best answer.